# Name of object in array causes a change in order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dynamic-arrays

With the following code:

```
//turn items into an array
$item_array = array('abc','xyz2','Good','nice-b');

//implode items, turn into string
$item_implode = join("','", $item_array);

//declare an overall array for result
$product_items = array();

$productList = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name, WebsitePrice as price, WebsiteStock as stock from table_products where Name IN ('$item_implode')");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $x = 1;
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $product_items[$x]["Name"] = $row['Name'];
        $product_items[$x]["price"] = $row['price'];
        $product_items[$x]["stock"] = $row['stock'];
        $x = $x + 1;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
abc- 99 - yes
xyz - 20 - yes
Good - 30 - yes
nice-b - 55 - yes
```

But when I use an item called `Hello1` instead of `Good`, like this:

```
$item_array = array('abc','xyz2','Hello1','nice-b');
```

I'm getting this output:

```
abc- 99 - yes
Hello1 - 77 - yes
xyz - 20 - yes
nice-b - 55 - yes
```

Meaning that the name of the object is causing some change in the order of the array, and it becomes the ***second*** item, even though it should be the ***third*** one.

What's causing this?

Comment: It might be in the db order or possibly based on the db primary key

Comment: shouldn't the order be exactly as the order that I type it in the array brackets? how do I avoid such dependency?

Comment: add `ORDER BY FIELD(Name, 'abc','xyz2','Good','nice-b');`

Comment: but that will make everything not dynamic anymore. I want to type the names of the items only once, like in the current code.

Comment: Use the `$item_implode` in the query

Comment: @Thamizhan Great, I this has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY FIELD(Name, 'abc','xyz2','Good','nice-b');` in your query. You could use `$item_implode` for reusability.

[Fetched from comments]

Answer (score 0):

> In the SQL world, order is not an inherent property of a set of data. Thus, you get no guarantees from your RDBMS that your data will come back in a certain order -- or even in a consistent order -- unless you query your data with an ORDER BY clause.

There is no guarantee that MySQL will return the results in the order you set the IDs in the `IN` clause.

**Later edit**: Based on your last comment you can do something like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $product_items = array_flip($item_array);

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $product_items[$row['Name']] = array();

        $product_items[$row['Name']]["Name"]  = $row['Name'];
        $product_items[$row['Name']]["price"] = $row['price'];
        $product_items[$row['Name']]["stock"] = $row['stock'];
    }
}
```

Comment: so my whole method of appending an index is faulty, as I will never know in advance what index is related to a particular item? what else could I do to achieve what I want?

Comment: you can simply add an order column and order the results by that column

Comment: column in the database? but I don't want to create such a dependency. I want to decide about everything right in my code. this code is going to be used in various pages, and each time I might want to sort items differently per page.

Comment: Using `Order` as  Thamizhan suggested sorted it out, in your new code, I'm not sure I understand what's going on - what happened to the indexing? I need a set of variables created for each item (price, stock, name), so that's what the indexing did.

Comment: What I did preserve the initial order set in the first array. There is no need for that index as the product name is unique in your array. give it a try to  understand how it works.. you will learn something new probably. The solution you have chosen is good as well.. good luck

Comment: I'm not very in good with programming so i don't understand much about how to further go with this, but i guess this means that later on in the code, whenever i want to call a variable, it would mean that I have to mention the name of the item, rather than the index. so if I plan to make this a template for various pages, it would be easier to use indexing, wouldn't it? as in such case I will only have to change item names on top, and not also later in the code.